# Facebook App Request Dialogue not being triggered after Ajax load (Rails Turbolinks)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-javascript-sdk, turbolinks

I cannot figure out how to get the Facebook javascript to load after a click event, which triggers an Ajax request with Turbolinks.

I got the rest of my Javascript to work using, but this is just not happening.

I have used all sorts of varieties on this code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

I have tried to implement everything mentioned here:
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/25

I have tried doing the same stuff that got all the rest of the JS working, which is to trigger a page:load call with Turbolinks.

Nothing is working.

Comment: Do you get any kind of errors in your JavaScript console when loading the page and clicking the link?

Comment: It depends on which solution I am going for, but if I use the out of the box method, I get this: Uncaught [object Object] all.js:38
i all.js:38
m.isTruthy all.js:38
r all.js:74
q.showLoader all.js:91
ca.iframe all.js:95
o all.js:96
(anonymous function) all.js:80
(anonymous function) all.js:77
sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector 1:21
onclick

Answer (score 0):

I also found my Facebook dialogs stopped firing after an Ajax load, but it had nothing to do with Facebook.  With Turbolinks, you have to bind your click handlers on the `page:load` event (or perhaps use event delegation on the body element) - otherwise they get lost.  See the [Railscast on Turbolinks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks) and also "[Page Change Events](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events)".

Example:

**projects.js.coffee.erb**

```
ready = ->
  $('a').click (event) ->
    alert('do something facebooky')
    event.preventDefault()

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

In my case, I had to also change the way Facebook was loaded.  See [this issue](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/25) and [corresponding solution](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html).  Here's my code from my canvas app.

**application.html.erb**

```
<!-- I used no other facebook code -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

**facebook.js.coffee.erb**

```
#
# Get Facebook working with Turbo Links
# see: http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html
#

fb_root = null
fb_events_bound = false

$ ->
  loadFacebookSDK()
  bindFacebookEvents() unless fb_events_bound

bindFacebookEvents = ->
  $(document)
    .on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot)
    .on('page:load', ->
      FB?.XFBML.parse()
    )
  fb_events_bound = true

saveFacebookRoot = ->
  fb_root = $('#fb-root').detach()

restoreFacebookRoot = ->
  if $('#fb-root').length > 0
    $('#fb-root').replaceWith fb_root
  else
    $('body').append fb_root

loadFacebookSDK = ->
  window.fbAsyncInit = initializeFacebookSDK
  $.getScript("//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1")

initializeFacebookSDK = ->
  FB.init
    appId     : "<%= ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] %>"
    channelUrl: "//" + window.location.host + "/channel.html"
    status    : true
    cookie    : true
    xfbml     : true
    frictionlessRequests  : true

  # Listen to the auth.login which will be called when the user logs in
  # using the Login button
  FB.Event.subscribe 'auth.login', (response) ->
    # We want to reload the page now so Ruby can read the cookie that the
    # Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
    # window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
    # post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
    # user asking if they want to send data again.
    window.location = window.location


  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()
```